# Is there any situation where it is interesting to rewrite the terms of a sequence as the partial sums of a series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, analysis

Any sequence $(a_n)\in\mathbb C^\mathbb N$ can always be re-written as a sequence of partial sums $\left(\sum_{k=0}^n u_k\right)$ for some sequence $(u_k)\in\mathbb C^\mathbb N$ (for instance, take $u_0=a_0$ and $u_n=a_n-a_{n-1}$ when $n\geq 1$).

My question is, are there any situations where this transformation would make it easier to study the sequence $(a_n)$? For example, are there any cases where this method would make it easier to determine if $(a_n)$ is convergent or divergent, or to compute its limit?